# getting value from void function with printf

Tags: c

I am trying to understand following C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int k = m();
    printf("%d", k);
}
void m()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

Above code produces output of `hello5`. I understand why it is printing `hello`, but I do not understand why there is `5` behind it. How the `5` is getting returned and stored into variable `k`? How does the flow of this program work?

Comment: Plain old undefined behavior.

Comment: Turn up your compile warning level and it will likely complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning return value of `m()` to `k`. Since `m()` has no return value undefined behaviour will be visible, so there will be "garbage" in `k` (in this case: 5).

Comment: `5` is not a garbage value. If I replace `hello` with `helo` then the output will be `helo4`. The number is length of string in `printf` statement.

Comment: And you could in theory get just about any value. In practice, probably whatever is left in the RAX register.

Comment: It is absolutely a garbage value. Just because you find a pizza slice in a box of pizza that I've thrown away, and you eat it, doesn't mean that you aren't eating garbage.

Comment: @BhaveshJadav: It's undefined by the language. You're seeing an artifact of one compiler's implementation of the language. Change the machine architecture, the compiler, the compiler version, even the compiler options, and you might get different results.

Comment: @BhaveshJadav I wonder of what C compiler you are using, as mine throws an error: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be.